# How to Generate SAF-T XML (Standard Audit File)

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I need to generate the SAF-T XML and using pandas dataframe, but I am very new for generating SAF-T XML using python.

Below is the output which I am expecting

```
<root xmlns:nl="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:NO" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:NO XML Final.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AuditFile>
        <Header>
            <AuditFileVersion>val1</AuditFileVersion>
            <Company>
                <Name>val3</Name>
            </Company>
        </Header>
    </AuditFile>
</root>
```

*Below is the code which I am using*
Library import

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from lxml import etree
```

Creating dataframe

```
data_section1 = {'col1': ['val1', 'val2']}
df_section1 = pd.DataFrame(data_section1)


data_section2 = {'col2': ['val3', 'val4']}
df_section2 = pd.DataFrame(data_section2)

# Combine results into a dictionary
dct_master = {
    'SECTION1': df_section1,
    'SECTION2': df_section2
}

data_xml = {
    'Row_seq': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'XML_File': ['XML_Final'] * 5,
    'Type': ['root', 'SECTION1', 'SECTION1', 'SECTION1', 'SECTION2'],
    'Path': ['', 'AuditFile', 'AuditFile/Header', 'Header/AuditFileVersion', 'Header/Company/Name'],
    'Col_tag': ['', 'AuditFile', 'Header', 'AuditFileVersion', 'Name'],
    'Col_Unbound': ['', '', '', 'col1', ''],
    'Col_Data': ['', '', 'col1', '', '']
}
```

Defining XML function

```
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(data_xml)print(dct_master)


lst_pth = []
var_pth = ''
var_create = 0
df_xml_part = pd.DataFrame(None)
def func_xml_create(df_xml_part):
    col_path_lst = re.findall('\(\s?(.+?)\s?\\)', df_xml_part.Path.unique()[0])
    col_unbnd_lst = np.unique(np.array(df_xml_part['Col_Unbound'].dropna().to_list())).tolist()
    col_data_lst = np.unique(np.array(df_xml_part['Col_Data'].dropna().to_list())).tolist()
    col_lstl = col_path_lst + col_unbnd_lst + col_data_lst
    col_lst = np.unique(col_lstl)
    print(col_path_lst, col_unbnd_lst, col_data_lst, col_lstl, col_lst)

    if col_lst.size > 0:
        dct_master_data = dct_master[df_xml_part.Type.unique()[0]][col_lst].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
        var_iter = len(dct_master_data.index)
    else:
        var_iter = 1

    while var_iter > 0:
        for indexl, rowl in df_xml_part.iterrows():
            path = df_xml_part['Path'][indexl]
            fold = df_xml_part['Col_tag'][indexl]
            fold_data = df_xml_part['Col_Data'][indexl]

            if str(df_xml_part.Col_Unbound[indexl]) != 'nan':
                unbnd_flg = 'Y'
                var_unbnd = len(dct_master_data[df_xml_part.Col_Unbound[indexl].split(',')].drop_duplicates())
                ar_unbnd_vall = dct_master_data[df_xml_part.Col_Unbound[indexl].split(',')].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1).to_numpy()
                ar_unbnd_val = ar_unbnd_vall[var_iter - 1]
            else:
                var_unbnd = 1
                unbnd_flg = 'N'

            regexp = re.compile(r'/')
            regexpl = re.compile(r'\(')

            if (var_unbnd != 1) or (unbnd_flg == 'Y'):
                fold_nm = fold + '-' + re.sub(r' [^\w]', '', str(ar_unbnd_val))
            else:
                fold_nm = fold

            path_nm = path
            for i in re.findall('\(\s?(.+?)\s?\\)', path_nm):
                lst = i.split(',')
                path_nm = re.sub(
                    r'[\s\+\.]',
                    '',
                    re.sub(
                        f'\({i}\)',
                        '-' + re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', dct_master_data[lst].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)[var_iter - 1]),
                        path_nm
                    )
                )

            if regexp.search(path_nm):
                for elemt in root.findall(path_nm):
                    child = ET.SubElement(elemt, fold_nm)
            else:
                for elemt in root.iter(path_nm):
                    child = ET.SubElement(elemt, fold_nm)
                var_unbnd = var_unbnd - 1

            if str(df_xml_part['Col_Data'][indexl]) != 'nan':
                child.text = str(eval(f'dct_master_data.{fold_data}')[var_iter - 1]).strip()

        var_iter = var_iter - 1


for index, rows in df_xml.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        name_space = {
            "xmlns:nl" : "urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:NO",
            "xsi:schemaLocation":"urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:NO XML Final.xsd",
            "xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        }
        root = ET.Element(df_xml[df_xml['Type' ]=='root']['Col_tag'][0],name_space)
    else:
        if (index!=1):
            if ((var_pth!=df_xml['Path'][index]) or (str(df_xml.Col_Unbound[index])!='nan')):
                print(df_xml_part)
                func_xml_create(df_xml_part)
                df_xml_part = pd.DataFrame(None)
        var_pth = df_xml['Path'][index]
        df_xml_part = df_xml_part._append(df_xml[['Type', 'Path', 'Col_tag','Col_Unbound', 'Col_Data']][index:index+1], ignore_index=True)
##### Handling end on XML file
print(df_xml_part)
func_xml_create(df_xml_part)
df_xml_part = pd.DataFrame()
```

Formatting the XML

```
regexp_no_data = re.compile(r'/>')
regexp_no_datal = re.compile(r'> <')
with open("XML_Finall.xml", "w") as text_file:
    print(BeautifulSoup(ET.tostring(root), "xml").prettify(), file=text_file)
#input file
fin = open("XML_Finall.xml", "rt")
#output file to write the result to
fout = open("XML_Final2.xml", "wt")
for l, line in enumerate(fin):
    if (l==0):
        fout.write(line)
    else:
        if (l==1):
            linel = re.sub(r'<','<nl:',line)
            line2 = re.sub(r'nl:/','/nl:',linel)
            fout.write(line2)
        else:
            linel = re.sub(r'<', '<nl:',line)
            line2 = re.sub(r'nl:/', '/nl:',linel)
            fout.write(re.sub(r'->', '>',re.sub(r'-[0-9a-zA-Z]+?>', '>', line2)))
#close input and output files
fin.close()
fout.close()


myparser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
abc = etree.parse('XML_Final2.xml', myparser)
for elem in abc.iter():
    if elem.text is not None:
        elem.text = elem.text.strip()
    if elem.tail is not None:
        elem.tail = elem.tail.strip()
#write the xml file with pretty print and xml encoding
abc.write('XML_Final3.xml', pretty_print=True, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
with open('XML_Final3.xml') as oldfile, open('XML_Final.xml', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not regexp_no_data.search(line):
            if not regexp_no_datal.search(line):
                newfile.write(line)
try:
    os.remove("XML_Finall.xml")
    os.remove("XML_Final2.xml")
    os.remove("XML_Final3.xml")
except OSError:
    pass
```

By running above code I am getting below error

```
dct_master_data = dct_master[df_xml_part.Type.unique()[0]][col_lst].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Can anyone help me to achieve the the XML generated as shown above and I am not sure why i am getting the issues. Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere in the code

Comment: Please trim the code down to a manageable [mcve]. Do you really need to use lxml, ElementTree, and BeautifulSoup in the same script?

Comment: I taught we need to use same script so I have kept in same script